# Add start element with prefix without namespace

Tags: c#, xml, xml-namespaces, prefix, xmlwriter

Is there any way to use WriteStartElement funtion in XmlWriter like this:

```
XmlWriter.WriteStartElement("prefix", "name", null);
```

> Error occured: System.ArgumentException: 'Unable to use prefix with
>   empty namespace.'

I do not want to set namespace URI when creating element.
Later on ill add it by WriteAttributeString(), when others attributes will be created.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, a namespace prefix unbound to a namespace URI is meaningless and not allowed in a [***namespace-well-formed***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25830482/290085) XML document.

Answer (score 1):

> I do not want to set namespace URI when creating element. Later on ill add it by WriteAttributeString(), when others attributes will be created.

A prefix always belongs to a namespace. By defining a non-nullnamespace the `xmlns` attribute will be automatically created:

```
writer.WriteStartElement("prefix", "localName", "ns"); // <prefix:localName xmlns:prefix="ns" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I was searching for a solution, eventually, I realized I should use the same namespace as I defined already.

I had something like this, to create the element:

```
xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("xhtml", "link", "xmlns");
```

the result was:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<urlset xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
    <url>
        <loc>https://www.my-site.com/en/home</loc>
        <xhtml:link rel="alternative" hreflang="en" href="https://www.my-site.com/en/home" xmlns:xhtml="xmlns" />
        <xhtml:link rel="alternative" hreflang="ar" href="https://www.my-site.com/fr/home" xmlns:xhtml="xmlns" />
        <xhtml:link rel="alternative" hreflang="fa" href="https://www.my-site.com/fa/home" xmlns:xhtml="xmlns" />
    </url>
</urlset>
```

the problem was the `xmlns:xhtml="xmlns"` in body of my `xhtml:link` elements:

```
<xhtml:link rel="alternative" hreflang="en" href="https://www.my-site.com/en/home" xmlns:xhtml="xmlns" />
```

so I put the `http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml` instead namespace or ns as below:

```
xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("xhtml", "link", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml");
```

and now it exactly became what I needed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<urlset xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
    <url>
        <loc>https://www.my-site.com/en/home</loc>
        <xhtml:link rel="alternative" hreflang="en" href="https://www.my-site.com/en/home" />
        <xhtml:link rel="alternative" hreflang="ar" href="https://www.my-site.com/fr/home" />
        <xhtml:link rel="alternative" hreflang="fa" href="https://www.my-site.com/fa/home" />
    </url>
</urlset>
```

Comment: It's good that you were able to work through your confusion regarding the arguments to `WriteStartElement`, but your problem is different:  OP's problem was in wanting to create an element with an undefined namespace prefix, which is not allowed in namespace-well-formed XML; your problem is that you simply misunderstood the purpose of the third argument to `WriteStartElement()` but were ok with the namespace prefix being bound to a namespace once you corrected your mistake.